# Socket.io Client error 404 not found

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am getting a 404 error (client side) on productive system. If i run the server in local network, everything is fine.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> GET https://foo.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MGd8e2F 404 (Not Found)

I am using socket.io Version 2.1.1 and Express 4.

Server.js

```
...
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var app = express();
httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app);
...
const io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer);

httpServer.listen(process.env.SERVER_HTTP_PORT);
httpsServer.listen(process.env.SERVER_HTTPS_PORT);

io.use(function (socket, next) {
    //Middleware (express-session)
    e_session(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});
io.on('connection', function (client) {
   ...
}
```

client.js

```
const socket = io('https://' + window.location.hostname + ':443');

socket.on('connect', function (data) {
  socket.emit('join', 'Server Connected to Client');
});
...
```

I tried also in client.js:

```
const socket = io();
const socket = io('https://' + window.location.hostname);
```

Why can not the client connect to the server on the production system?

Comment: Maybe (most likely) you already have something running on port 443 on your prod server. An Apache or Nginx server for exemple

Comment: @Seblor its running in a empty docker alpine container. if something would running on port 80 or 443, the server couldn't start and/or i couldn't load the page. Or i am wrong?

Comment: AFAIK, a socker.io server will not crash if the port is already taken. Running on a Docker container doesn't change anything (network-wise). If a port on an IP is taken, you can only access the server running on that port (unless said server has a virtual host settings / proxy set up). Edit : I suggest you run a nmap on your IP or hostname to see what port are taken. However, only a web server will return a 404 error, since "404 - not found" is an HTTP error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake: The Load Balancer on the productive system sends the HTTP request to Port 80 but socket.io was listening to Port 443. I initiated socket.io with the wrong server: 
`const io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer);` instead of 
`require('socket.io')(httpServer)`.